# PHP get from string

Tags: php, parsing

```
$var = '<img src="http://site.com/some_directory/filename.png"/>';
```

`png` can be replaced with any extension.

How to cut everything, except "**filename**" part?

And write into new variable. In this case:

```
$name = 'filename';
```

One more example:

```
$var = '<img src="http://site.com/directory/subdirectory/Pakahontos.txt"/>';
$name = 'Pakahontos';
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
preg_match('#([^/]+)\.\w+"#', $var, $matches);
$name = $matches[1];
```

Note that if `$var` is actually more complicated (e.g. has arbitrary HTML), you must use other methods (see e.g. [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/DOMDocument)).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic [HTML-parsing tutorial](http://www.web-development-blog.com/archives/parse-html-with-preg_match_all/) with preg_match. It's parsing images in the example.